# Javascript - Create Iterable Abstraction Layer

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Assuming I have an object like this:

```
var result = {
    items: [
        'item1', 'item2', 'item3'
    ]
}
```

I'm looking for a way create an object that would abstract my result object and yet would remain compatible to it:

```
function wrapper(result) {
    this.items = ???
}
```

In order to able able to do this

```
var p = new wrapper(result);

for(var x = 0; x < p.items.length; x++) {
    console.log(p[x]) // = item1, item2, item3
}
```

This can be easily accomplished in PHP using ArrayIterator. I was wondering if it can be done in JS, specifically in NodeJS.

Just to clarify:

Imagine the original object is a result from a db query. However, the formatting of that result object cannot be fed into the consumer as-is and needs to be adapted. In this case I did not dwell on the adaptation but for the sake of the example assume each value needs to be uppercased.

Additionally, the original list is very large. I could obviously iterate, copy all values and uppercase them, but in most cases it will not be required for all values, therefore it would be inefficient to do this for all items every time. The idea of the wrapper is to act as a proxy that I would be able to iterate. The wrapper will in turn retrieve the result from the original object, and modify it on the fly.

Comment: To make your code work you would just assign this.items to result.items. Does that answer your question?

Comment: `this.items = result.items;` ... ? And why create an object that looks exactly the same as the object you start out with? I think you are over-thinking this.

Comment: Can you describe what problem you're really trying to solve here because what you're asking for does not seem necessary or useful when you can just assign or copy the array anywhere you want to.  There is no generic reason to put a wrapper object around an array.  It's already a fully functioning object.  Now, if you have a specific problem you're trying to solve, then we could participate in the best ways to solve that, but you'd have to describe the real end objective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Node 4 or 5 you can consider using ES6's `Symbol.Iterator`. It's the closest thing to PHP's `ArrayIterator` that I can think of.

Here's an example of a use-case which you describe in your post:

```
'use strict';

let result = {
  items: [
    'item1', 'item2', 'item3'
  ],
  [Symbol.iterator](cb) {
    let index = 0;
    return {
      next: () => {
        let value = this.items[index];
        let done = index >= this.items.length;
        // Note that arrow functions won't bind `this.items` to cb's `this`.
        if (typeof cb === 'function') {
          return cb.call(this.items, value, done, this.items, index++);
        } else {
          index++;
          return { value, done };
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

let cb = (value, done, items, index) => {
  // Modify original array.
  items[index] = items[index] && items[index].toUpperCase();
  value = items[index];
  return { value, done };
};

let iterator1 = result[Symbol.iterator](cb);
let iterator2 = result[Symbol.iterator]();
console.log(iterator1.next()); // { value: 'ITEM1', done: false }
console.log(iterator2.next()); // { value: 'ITEM1', done: false }
console.log(iterator1.next()); // { value: 'ITEM2', done: false }
console.log(iterator1.next()); // { value: 'ITEM3', done: false }
console.log(result.items); // [ 'ITEM1', 'ITEM2', 'ITEM3' ]
```

Note that you can define multiple iterators to iterate concurrently, modify the referenced array, and add your own methods to the iterator to emulate `ArrayIterator` as you please.

I should also mention that the `for-of` construct works well with this:

```
'use strict';

let result = {
  items: [
    'item1', 'item2', 'item3'
  ]
}

let cb = (value, done, items, index) => {
  // Modify original array.
  items[index] = items[index] && items[index].toUpperCase();
  value = items[index];
  return { value, done };
};

let modifiableIterableIterator = {
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    let index = 0;
    return {
      next: () => {
        let value = result.items[index];
        let done = index >= result.items.length;
        // Note that arrow functions won't bind `this.items` to cb's `this`.
        if (typeof cb === 'function') {
          return cb.call(result.items, value, done, result.items, index++);
        } else {
          index++;
          return { value, done };
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

for (let item of modifiableIterableIterator) console.log(item);
```

`modifiableIterableIterator[Symbol.iterator]` is the same as the previous `result[Symbol.iterator]`, except there is no more `cb` parameter. When passing an iterable iterator (an **iterable iterator** is one that defines a `next` method, and `Symbol.iterator` on the object), no arguments are passed to `Symbol.iterator`, so we just make the callback explicit from within the method. The loop will perform the same operations as before: uppercase all the values and modify the array in-place.

There are some design decisions about how this can be structured properly, but this is up to you and the way your application is structured.

---

Since you want to support the "older" way to iterate while maintaining this behavior, the only way you can do this by overloading `[]` is to use ES6's `Proxy` object. This allows you to do some metaprogramming. Unfortunately, the native support is lacking, but you can use shims if you need to (I got this working on Node 5 using the `harmony-reflect` module and passing `--harmony_proxies` on the command-line).

```
let proxy = new Proxy(result.items, {
  get(target, index) {
    target[index] = target[index] && target[index].toUpperCase();
    return target[index];
  }
});
for (let x = 0; x < result.items.length; x++) console.log(proxy[x]); // 'ITEMx'
console.log(result.items); // [ 'ITEM1', 'ITEM2', 'ITEM3' ]
```

Combine the new iterators feature and a Proxy, and you have a solution which works with your existing implementation and future-proof's your code.

Comment: This looks very close to what I'm looking for. I'll play with this a bit and if I manage to solve my problem I'll accept it. Thank you !

Comment: I've copy pasted both examples and they work as described. However neither of them allows me to actually iterate using: for(var x = 0; x < p.items.length; x++) syntax which is my requirement. There is a considerable amount of underlying code already "walking" through results this way, and I want to keep that.

Comment: This answer is the correct way. If you're having problems make sure you have everything up-to-date and are using a good editor. I've had a few issues with `let` when using an inferior editor.

Comment: @AnthonyCalandra great response. I think you've covered nearly the whole subject. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a class similar to `ArrayIterator`.

1. [Create an npm module](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules)
2. Put this in your module's `index.js`:

   ```
   function wrapper( items ) {
       this.items = items;
       this.count = items.length;
       this.iterateReverse = ( cb ) => {
           var x = this.count;
           while ( x-- ) cb( this.items[ x ] );
       }
       this.iterate = ( cb ) => {
           var x = -1;
           while ( x++ < this.count-1 ) cb( this.items[ x ] );
       }
   }

   wrapper.prototype.items = (this.items);

   module.exports = wrapper;
   ```
3. Now in your main environment:

   ```
   const
       wrapper = require( './wrapper' );

   var p = new wrapper( [ 'item1', 'item2', 'item3' ] );

   for( var x = 0; x < p.count; x++ ) {
       console.log( p.items[x] ); // = item1, item2, item3
   }

   p.iterateReverse(( v ) => {
       console.log( v ); // = item3, item2, item1
   });

   p.iterate(( v ) => {
       console.log( v ); // = item1, item2, item3
   });
   ```

This will result with `// = item1, item2, item3`